# Pulling all files within a subfolder in Git repository

Tags: git, github, directory, bitbucket, pull

I am trying to pull all the files and folders within a specific folder in my git repository. I have already tried using sparce-checkout but this pulls the specific folder. I wish for it to only pull the files **within** the folder.

I have a folder called /EWINS/ and I wish to pull every folder and file within that directory.

I have tried:

git init

git config core.sparseCheckout true

git remote add -f origin https://MYDIRECTORY

echo "EWINS/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

git pull origin master

However this results in the folder EWINS being pulled where as I require all the items within EWINS.

I have referenced:
[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951)

http://lakehanne.github.io/git-sparse-checkout

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a previous stack-overflow-er has answered

This is called a **[sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/278405)**, available since version 1.7.0.

> "Sparse checkout" allows populating the working directory sparsely. It uses the `skip-worktree` bit (see `git-update-index`) to tell Git whether a file in the working directory is worth looking at.
>
> While `$GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout` is usually used to specify what files are in, you can also specify what files are not in, using negate patterns. For example, to remove the file `unwanted`:
>
> ```
> /*
> !unwanted
> ```

See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/278405) and [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) for details.